# Как в админ_панели django определять (давать) более информативные имена?

Tags: python, django-admin

[image]

Вместо "Post object" мне нужно, чтобы было, например: "My first post", "My second post" и т.д.
Это мои файлы с содержимым. Что в них нужно изменить или добавить для решения моего вопроса?

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Заголовок') # заголовок поста
datetime = models.DateTimeField('Дата публикации') # дата публикации
content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, verbose_name='Текст') # текст поста

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/blog/%i/" % self.id
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

ps: python3.4 and django1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в модели реализовать метод `__str__`:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=255,)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Дата публикации',) 
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000, verbose_name='Текст',)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/blog/{0}/'.format(self.id)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

Подробная [документация](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/models/instances.html#django.db.models.Model.__str__) на русском языке.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!